# Refresh Front-End on Data Change in Database by Other User in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am using C# as Front End with multiple users, which is connected to a SQL Server 2008. My question is: if one user changes the data using an update operation, how can other user see the impact of that update statement without using `Select *` command or `sda.fill`?

I have thousands of records in my table which takes too much time on refill.

Here is code I am using to update data.

```
MyGlobalVariables.bsInc.EndEdit();
MyGlobalVariables.con.Open();
MyGlobalVariables.CmdString = "Update Increment set IncAmount=" + Convert.ToInt32(txtInc.Text) + ", EditedBy='"+MyGlobalVariables.MyUname+"', editedOn=sysdatetime() where IncYear=" + Convert.ToInt16(cmbIncYear.Text) + " and EmpCode='" + MyGlobalVariables.MyEmpCode + "'";
MyGlobalVariables.cmd = new SqlCommand(MyGlobalVariables.CmdString, MyGlobalVariables.con);
MyGlobalVariables.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MyGlobalVariables.con.Close();
MyGlobalVariables.ds.Tables["Increment"].Rows[MyGlobalVariables.bsInc.Position].AcceptChanges();
MyGlobalVariables.MyParentForm.lblProg.Text = "Record Updated Successfully.";
```

Comment: If the data has changed, you **must** reload it to show it - no other way

Comment: Means I will have to use select * command again? Isn't there any other way. I am using My Software on WAN which take atleast 40to50 sec on first fill. Will I have to wait to that much time on every refresh?

Comment: There is SignalR framework for real time communication. But I'm not sure if that is compatible with your existing system.

Comment: Actually the problem is that i have a single application which is being used by more than one user. Now one is entering the data and other is reviewing it.

In the first phase, my problem is that my first user (who enter a new record using insert query) is not able to view the newly inserted record, although the insert process is successful and inserts the new row in the database.

Secondly, i want that record to be shown on the second users interface by clicking a refresh button.

Keep in mind both the users have same data with different logins.

Comment: You could run a method in a separate thread that looks for changes in the table receiving the inserts at an interval using a Timer and include some logic in that method to prompt refreshing your page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution of my problem. Here is my code after Insert Process.

```
SqlDataAdapter sdaTemp = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
MyGlobalVariables.con.Open();
sdaTemp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Increment where ecode=(select MAX(ecode) from Increment) and UserID='"+MyGlobalVariables.MyUid+"'", MyGlobalVariables.con);
MyGlobalVariables.con.Close();
sdaTemp.Fill(dtTemp);
MyGlobalVariables.dtEmp.Merge(dtTemp);
MyGlobalVariables.dtEmp.AcceptChanges();
MyGlobalVariables.bsEmp.MoveLast();
```

Thanks everybody for your suggestions.